# Convert speech to text while pressing and holding space bar (Streamlit app)

Tags: speech-recognition, keyboard-events, streamlit

I am developing a simple Streamlit webapp that needs to do the following:

1. User presses and holds down the space button and speaks
2. When the user releases the space button, what they said is converted to text and returned to the UI

Below is the code that I have so far.  I have the speech to text working when the user presses a button and then speaks.  This is not ideal as the listener sometimes misses the start of the speech or cuts off too soon. I cannot get it to work while holding down the space bar which is what I need.  I think the speech needs to be captured first while the space bar is pressed and then the speech to text carried out on that "file", rather than the current streaming approach.

```
import streamlit as st
import speech_recognition as sr #(SpeechRecognition in pypi) 

def transcribe_speech():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        with st.spinner("Listening..."):
            audio = r.listen(source)
            st.write("Transcribing...")
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                return text
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                st.write("Could not understand audio")
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                st.write("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

ready_button = st.button("TALK TO ME", key='ready_button')

if ready_button:
    text = transcribe_speech()
    if text:
        st.write(f"You said: {text}")
```

In terms of getting the space bar working, I thought this would work, but the app just hangs, no times are printed.

```
import keyboard
import time

def print_current_time():
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    st.write(f"Current time: {current_time}")

space_pressed = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(" "):
        st.write("if keyboard.is_pressed")
        if not space_pressed:
            st.write("if not space_pressed")
            space_pressed = True
            print_current_time()
    else:
        space_pressed = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pip package.

To install,

```
pip install whisper-mic
```

Code snippet:

```
from whisper_mic.whisper_mic import WhisperMic
import streamlit as st

mic = WhisperMic()
result = mic.listen()
st.write(result)
```